# VS Code: Even after starting a "New terminal" window, old terminal still appears on re-running the code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

```
int num;

printf("Please Enter your number: \n");
scanf("%d", &num);

printf("So, the output will be : %d\n", num * num);

return 0;
```

}

/* Intially I run the code , everything was good. i gave 3 inputs & i got 3 outputs.

then i thought of clearing it & by clicking on " TERMINAL" option --> i selected " NEW TERMINAL" .

SO, NOW WHEN I RUN THE CODE, NOW MY TERMINAL SHOULD BE NEW, BUT WHAT I SEE IS ALL THE THINGS I HAD IN MY OLD TERMINAL IN NEW TERMINAL & ALSO SOME OF THE INPUTS WHICH I DIDN'T & ALSO I GOT OUTPUT 0.

[image: New terminal I wanted but still everything of previous terminal came in this]

*/

I went to settings & then in terminal selected this ( in pic ). but it still didn't worked.
[image: terminal setting]

I closed the app and even i restarted my laptop.
I reinstalled VS code but none worked it didn't worked till yesterday it was working fine.